# VM Azure "We couldn't connect because there are currently no available resources"

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I am currently trying to set up a VM in Microsoft azure and still have little knowledge about Azure. I created a Pool and assigned a user to it. When I go to https://client.wvd.microsoft.com/arm/webclient/index.html and try to connect the the VM it shows "Oops, we couldn't connect to "SessionDesktop"
We couldn't connect because there are currently no available resources. Try again later or if this keeps happening, ask your admin or tech support for help." What are some possible solutions? Thanks in advance

I though it should be rather easy but this message is confusing me.

Answer (score 1):

Some times just forcing logoff disconnected users works.
My case the issue was related to Max session limit session setting (too low)

Always check Azure server status to see if you're down locally or Azure has an issue https://status.azure.com/en-gb/status